# Reduce font size to avoid text wrapping in mobile

Tags: css, html, wordpress, mobile, media-queries

Please refer to my website http://www.checkgaadi.com. It renders fine on a desktop but on any mobile browser the main site logo text wraps to the next line. I have used '*em*' to specify the text size in the CSS (below) so I expect the font size to reduce so that the text fits into the available width. How do I achieve this?

```
#site-logo {
    font: bold 5em/1em 'Segoe UI';
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

Someone suggested to use media queries to achieve this but I have no clue...can someone give me a few pointers (or sample code) so I can proceed?

Comment: Have a look at `vw` units, which are proportional to the screen width.  Assuming you're targeting modern browsers (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: What Hobo said...... plus... you should always nowadays only uses what is knows as a 'responsive' theme.